# I need to hide last node in tree using css

Tags: html, css

I have tree built using html, css I need to hide last node in the tree
my css code is:

`div ul li ul li ul li ul.treeview{
     display: none;
   }`

but did not work, what is the problem?

Markup:

```
<div id="field-term-parent-value-wrapper" class="form-item form-item-labeled">
    <div id="field-term-parent-value" class="tm-processed">
<ul class="treeview">
<li class="collapsable">
<ul class="treeview" style="display: block;">
<li class="collapsable">
<ul class="treeview" style="display: block;">
  data
```

Comment: Share your nested markup

Comment: It's impossible with pure CSS. CSS only looks backwards. No element knows if it's the last one.

Comment: please share your markup

Comment: If this is the whole markup then your selector will not select anything at all.

Comment: You Jan is right here, you are using way out of what you should use..what you wan to specifically hide?.

Comment: no this not all markup because my markup is big and the system did not allow me to post all of it

Comment: I would better recommend you to give the last node a class rather than nesting the styles`(IF IT'S NOT GENERATED DYNAMICALLY)`

Comment: As I said, if you need to hide the last element, you need to mark it with a class. It's not possible to do this in pure CSS.

Comment: @AymanHussein _don't post code into the comments. It's unreadable there_

Comment: Which **tree** are you referring to, and how do you define the **last** node of the tree? Please specify that in HTML terms.

Comment: Would you mind reducing the code to strip away the irrelevant parts? Also, would you mind using correct indentation? Otherwise it's still unreadable without the indentation.

Comment: Still am not seeing any nested `ul li`

Comment: I have posted correct markup in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
div ul li ul li ul li ul.treeview { display: none !important; }
```

because your inline styles in the element override your other styles defined for this element.

P.S I assume you know your markup and put correct number of `ul` and `li` in the CSS declaration. What you pasted suggest that there are only three `ul` and two `li` there, so this would work:

```
div ul li ul li ul.treeview { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you Soooooooooooo much => !important the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I find works in these situations is toggling class names instead of directly setting 'display: block'. This prevents the need for crazy selectors or using !important.

```
/* the default is display:block, so all we need
   is this one class */

.closed {
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
<li class="collapsable">
<ul class="treeview">
<li class="collapsable">
<ul class="treeview" class="closed">
```